# Phonegap Ajax and wampserver/php

Tags: php, ajax, cordova, wamp

I am currently trying to simply get Ajax to 'activate' a php file on wampserver
Better to show the code that explain I think
The following is a function activated by a button, the HTML/JS all works fine

```
var jsonString = "";
function jsonconversion(){

    jsonString = JSON.stringify(myArr);
    return jsonString;
    console.log(jsonString);

    $.ajax({        
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/xx/index2.php",
       data: jsonString,
    complete: function() {
            console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function() {
           console.log("Function: forward_to_server() error")
    }
    }); 
}
```

However, I can't seem to access the php file. For ease, I am not even using the jsonString in the php file, instead I am simply trying to post some integers into a database on wamp. The php file loaded by itself works fine

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xx";
$dbname = "xx";

//$myArray = $_REQUEST['jsonString'];
$myArray = array(100,1,19);

$con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password ,$dbname) or die ("could not connect database");
echo $myArray;

$keys = array_keys($myArray);              // get the value of keys
$rows = array();                         // create a temporary storage for rows
foreach($keys as $key) {                 // loop through
    $value = $myArray[$key];               // get corresponding value
    $rows[] = "('" . $key . "', '" . $value . "')";
                                         // add a row to the temporary storage 
}
$values = implode(",", $rows);           // 'glue' your rows into a query
$sql = "INSERT INTO php_test (temp, sound, light) VALUES (10,20,30)"; //. $values
$rs = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

$con->close();

?>
```

However when I call the function in phonegap, it doesn't seem to work, I have no errors either which is hurting the process :(

Wamp server is 'online' and I can access it from the internet.

Any guidance on this?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Take the `return jsonString;` line out of your javascript code and the javascript may execute as far as the ajax call

Comment: Replace `url: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/xx/index2.php",` with `url: "xx/index2.php"` and the code will work anywhere rather than just on this PC

Comment: Thanks riggs....I hate myself right now, can't believe how much time I spent for the most obvious thing ever XD...:'(

Comment: We all do it from time to time. Thats why a dev should not do the testing. We only ever test what we wrote and not what we were supposed to write et al we also only see what we think we coded and not what is actually there